# Computational geometry - BSP tree

Tags: geometry, computer-science, computational-geometry

I am doing some exercises from my textbook and I have stuck by this one. Any help would be great

> Give an example of a set S of n non-intersecting line segments in the
> plane for which a BSP tree of size n exists, whereas any
> auto-partition of S has size at least 4n/3 .

So far I have tried following, but I am not sure if this is the right path for my problem

To provide a simple estimate: let's say each segment splits at least one other segment when used as the splitting line (this is a conservative estimate, especially when n is large). If we build the BSP tree using the middle segment strategy, we will split roughly n/2 segments, creating an extra n/2 fragments. Thus, the auto-partitioned BSP tree will have at least n+n/2=3n/2 nodes. For larger n and considering segments may split more than one segment when used as the splitting line, the number could be more in line with the 4n/3 stated.

Comment: For those who have not studied the subject - Could you summarize what exactly characterizes an "auto-partition"? Naïvely thinking, I would assume that "auto-partition" is any partition that has been automatically generated by an algorithm. If there exists an optimal partition, then I would assume that there is an algorithm out there that is capable of finding it, ignoring questions about time and memory complexity. This is apparently _not_ the definition of "auto-partition", otherwise the question would not make sense. So what is it?

Comment: @ReinhardMeier For a set of planar polygons
in 3-space, an auto-partition is a BSP that only uses planes through the input
polygons as splitting planes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following works:

[image: BSP difficulties]

The red line segment is not part of $S$, it just shows that a BSP of size $n$ can be done manually.

The first step of the auto-partition already produces $\left\lfloor\frac{4n}{3}\right\rfloor$ fragments in total.

In order to show that there will be at least $\frac{4n}{3}$ fragments (without the rounding), you would have to show that there is one more split in one of the next steps. But I think the claim is only meant to hold for the rounded result, anyway (consider the cases $n=1$ and $n=2,$ in which the statement "Any auto-partition of $S$ has size at least $\frac{4n}{3}$" is wrong.)

Note: I assume that "size of partition" means the number of fragments we have in the end.

Comment: Thanks! It's much more clear now